# SharePoint Sites go into read-only when SQL Server Backup is running

Tags: sql-server-2005, sharepoint-2007, database-backup, sql-server

I have SharePoint 2007. When the database backups run using SQLCMD, SharePoint sites go into read-only. Users can't add anything to the sites and the buttons are grayed out. On the backend the databases do not get set to read-only. My question is this, is this normal with SharePoint? I have read some forums that say SharePoint does this by default but the information is a little murky.

Comment: Why the h*** do run database backup during business hours?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Maybe his business hours are 24/7

Answer (score 1):

This is standard practice. You wouldn't want your users trying to submit changes to a database that is being backed up. Also, stop doing backups during production hours. Schedule them for after-hours or something. It's very poor practice to do otherwise.

Comment: It is 24X7 and we have a set of users that edit a log for turnover for the next shift. SQL 2005 t-sql backups do not lock or put databases in read-only. My question is, is this normal for sharepoint?

Comment: Yes this is normall for sharepoint.